# Can VS Code code completion be configured to accept a suggestion on punctuation?

Tags: javascript, c#, typescript, visual-studio-code

This question is particularly pointed at other C# devs coming over to TypeScript in VS Code.

I fell in love with the code completion in VS C#. To illustrate, say I'm trying to write:

```
console.log('hello')
```

Using C#, I would have:

1. type "con"
2. a list of suggestions would appear, probably starting with "console"
3. since that's highlighted and it's what I want, hitting "." will write out "sole." so now I have: `console.`
4. type "l", "log" is the first suggestion
5. type "(", now I have: `console.log('')`
6. cursor is now in the ''
7. type "hello"

Currently with my VS Code setup, the same thing can be achieved in JS/TS hitting `tab` each time I want to accept a suggestion. But just hitting the next punctuation to proceed was really nice and, if you forgive me for caring about it, "fun." I miss it. And there's no technical limitation of the languages that I know of that would prohibit this behavior.

Anyone know if there's any extension or setting available to enable this? Or else, where else this conversation may be occurring ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can implement this oneself using the [macros extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=geddski.macros#overview). To do this:

1. Install the [macros extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=geddski.macros#overview)
2. Create a macro calling the acceptSelectedSuggestion action, then type `.`. Here's what my Settings.json looked like:

   ```
   {
       "editor.wordWrap": "on",
       "window.zoomLevel": 0,
       "git.enableSmartCommit": true,
       "macros": {
           "accept.": [
               "acceptSelectedSuggestion",
               {"command": "type", "args": {"text": "."}}
           ],
           "accept(": [
               "acceptSelectedSuggestion",
               {"command": "type", "args": {"text": "("}}
           ],        
           "accept=": [
               "acceptSelectedSuggestion",
               {"command": "type", "args": {"text": "="}}
           ]
       }
   }
   ```
3. Added each of these macros to a key binding in keybindings.json. My additional keybindings looked like:

   ```
   {
       "key": ".",
       "command": "macros.accept.",
       "when": "editorTextFocus && suggestWidgetVisible"
   },
   {
       "key": "shift+9",
       "command": "macros.accept(",
       "when": "editorTextFocus && suggestWidgetVisible"
   },
   {
       "key": "=",
       "command": "macros.accept=",
       "when": "editorTextFocus && suggestWidgetVisible"
   }
   ```

   This enables the classic VS C# completion behavior for these 3 specific follow-on keys. Any others I will think of can be added as I remember them.

Comment: Great, I've been missing this as well but don't use Code quite enough to have gone digging for it. But now that I know...

Comment: Note that a major limitation to this is lack of undo support. If you accidentally accept something with punctuation you don't want, you should be able to use undo to revert what's written to only what you wrote. This is probably properly scoped to a full VS Code Extension.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can add the `.` at the end of `console`, but you can do everything else:

Go to File >> Preferences >> Keyboard Shortcuts.

On the right side of the screen, a file called `keybindings.json` will come up.  Between the two brackets, insert this:

```
{ "key": ".",                   "command": "acceptSelectedSuggestion",
                                 "when": "editorTextFocus && suggestWidgetVisible" },
```

That should add the support for all languages.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ServerS. This only accepted the suggestion, didn't include typing the `.` as well, but it pointed me in the right direction to find the rest. See my answer for what I found.