# How can a Visual Studio Code extension directly add key bindings

Tags: vscode-extensions, visual-studio-code

## Question

How can a Visual Studio Code extension add key bindings to a workspace directly?

## Constraints

All settings should be contained within the extension, so that any modifications by the extension are easy to find in 1 place, and uninstalling the extension will remove any modifications.

## Scenario

I'm developing a VSCode extension which will need to listen for keystrokes. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36727520/capturing-keystrokes-in-visual-studio-code-extension) listens through the [vscode.workspace.onDidChangeTextDocument](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#TextDocumentChangeEvent) event, but I found that route a little messy in comparison to just creating key bindings for what I'm listening to. I found a pretty elegant way to [achieve what I want using key bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46452085/can-vs-code-code-completion-be-configured-to-accept-a-suggestion-on-punctuation), but the implementation is not scalable and not simply exportable for others to implement.

Therefore I want to write an extension that totally encapsulates any key binding additions that are necessary.

I did find the answer to this after a long night of research, so I just want to post the solution for others' benefit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.keybindings

This allows new keybindings to be declared right in the extension's package.json