# VSCode Extension API: How to listen for events like Ctrl+C

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am making a Visual Studio Code extension and I want to do something whenever the user enters a keystroke, including shortcuts like `Ctrl+C`.

I didn't find anything like this in the API, only the `onDidChangeTextDocument` function which only tells me when the document's text changes, which is not enough for my usecase (does not trigger on `Ctrl+C`).

Is there a function I missed in the API?

Thank you

Comment: You would have to add a keybinding for `Ctrl+C`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46615616/how-can-a-visual-studio-code-extension-directly-add-key-bindings

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57561242/vscode-extension-how-to-log-keystrokes